# Aviary activity crash

Tags: android, aviary

I am working on app using of Aviary SDK. When I call `loadAviaryActivityForImage(ImportDialog.imageFilePath)` next error are shown:

```
06-21 11:53:53.421  4534-4549/com.bigblueclip.picstitch.debug:aviarycds E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[AviaryCdsService]
 junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
                    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:48)
                    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
                    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:218)
                    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:211)
                    at com.aviary.android.feather.cds.AviaryCdsService.checkProviderExists(AviaryCdsService.java:785)
                    at com.aviary.android.feather.cds.AviaryCdsService.onHandleIntent(AviaryCdsService.java:302)
                    at com.aviary.android.feather.cds.AviaryIntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(AviaryIntentService.java:67)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

After that Aviary Activity run and give me valid image, so I don't know what's wrong. Does it mean that a problem is in Aviary SDK, not in my program?

Comment: This SDK works on Android 2.3 and above, so tell us in which Android os you have try these sample?

Comment: API 17-19 for running this app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with gradle build. In detail, I use ".debug" prefix for build my app, but Aviary worked wrong with such configuration.